# Does "provides the pinnacle of education" make sense?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, british-english

The phrase seems hardly used so I'm not sure if I can use the "pinnacle" like that. I can't seem to find another way to say what I want. Any clarification is appreciated! :)

Comment: Are you truing to say, "provides the ultimate in education"?

Comment: or provides the best education

Answer (score 2):

Using another actor in a sentence with the word 'pinnacle' is not good usage. 'Something' either 'is' the pinnacle or 'represents' the pinnacle of 'something'. '...provides the pinnacle' is grammatically okay but it's not proper usage.

Comment: +1 for the answer and "law on the sharp end" is a sharp phrase. Where'd you find it?

Comment: It's British, more commonly used in military and police jargon. The reference is to a spearpoint in ancient combat. Staff people in military and police organizations are what? (on the blunt end?) Infantry and cops on the beat are on the sharp end of the spear where things are messier.